# ggplot2: Faceting multiple regressions with slope & p-value labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, facet, anova

I thought I would share some code for those who ever struggled to automate adding R2, slope, intercept, p-value onto your multi-facet figures. This code shows you how to calculate your regression fits, and place them onto your figure as a labels for multiple regressions (ancova).

Bellow figure is how the figure looks like following a quick touchup in a vector software.

I tried annotating as many lines as possible. Hopefully this will help some of you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this example, I am comparing samples that have been irradiated by UV (light) to samples that have not been irradiated (dark)

## Start by importing && subsetting your data

```
#I called mine Ancovas. --> Note, export your df as .csv to work with it in R.

Ancovas <- read.csv("~/Dropbox/YOUR DATAFILE NAME.csv")

#Next, subset your data by the two conditions (e.g. "l"=light, "d"=dark), and both treatments (e.g. "MQ"=water, "DOM"=media)
 AncovasL <- Ancovas[(Ancovas$UV == "Light"), ]
 AncovasL.MQ <- AncovasL[(AncovasL$DOM == "MQ"), ]
 AncovasL.DOM <- AncovasL[(AncovasL$DOM == "DOM"), ]

 AncovasD <- Ancovas[(Ancovas$UV == "Dark"), ]
 AncovasD.MQ <- AncovasD[(AncovasD$DOM == "MQ"), ]    #This code only keeps what is inside the brackets
 AncovasD.DOM <- AncovasD[(AncovasD$DOM == "DOM"), ]  #Note, adding and "!" after square bracket removes what is in " ".
```

## Create a regression function

```
#--> this code was gathered from several sites.
 #note: I don't understand the logic of how the numbers in brackets are organized. But this essentially pulls some information from the fit model. i.e. [9] means find the 9th value in the list (I think) 

regression = function(Ancovas){
  fit       <-   lm(AvgBio ~ Exposure, data=Ancovas) 
  slope     <-   round(coef(fit)[2],1)  
  intercept <-   round(coef(fit)[1],0) 
  R2        <-   round(as.numeric(summary(fit)[8]),3)
  R2.Adj    <-   round(as.numeric(summary(fit)[9]),3)
  p.val     <-   signif(summary(fit)$coef[2,4], 3)
  c(slope,intercept,R2,R2.Adj, p.val)  }
```

## Now split regression data by TREATMENT and apply regression function

```
#Call your column "Treatments"   
 regressions_dataL.MQ  <- ddply(AncovasL.MQ,  "Treatment", regression)  #For light samples using water
 regressions_dataL.DOM <- ddply(AncovasL.DOM, "Treatment", regression)  #For light samples using media
 regressions_dataD.MQ  <- ddply(AncovasD.MQ,  "Treatment", regression)  #For dark samples using water
 regressions_dataD.DOM <- ddply(AncovasD.DOM, "Treatment", regression)  #For dark samples using media

#Rename columns 
 colnames(regressions_dataL.MQ)  <-c ("Treatment","slope","intercept","R2","R2.Adj","p.val")
 colnames(regressions_dataL.DOM) <-c ("Treatment","slope","intercept","R2","R2.Adj","p.val")
 colnames(regressions_dataD.MQ)  <-c ("Treatment","slope","intercept","R2","R2.Adj","p.val")
 colnames(regressions_dataD.DOM) <-c ("Treatment","slope","intercept","R2","R2.Adj","p.val")
```

## Creating the theme for the figures

```
#Yes I like to hyper control every aspect of my theme
 theme_new <- theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", linetype = "solid", colour = "black"), 
                 legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                 axis.text.x=element_text(size = 11, angle = 0, hjust=0.5),                          #axis numbers (set it to 1 to place it on left side, 0.5 for middle and 0 for right side)
                 axis.text.y=element_text(size = 13, angle = 0),                     
                 plot.title=element_text(size=15, vjust=0, hjust=0),                                #hjust 0.5 to center title 
                 axis.title.x=element_text(size=14),                                                #X-axis title
                 axis.title.y=element_text(size=14, vjust=1.5),                                     #Y-axis title
                 legend.position = "top",
                 legend.title = element_text(size = 11, colour = "black"),               #Legend title
                 legend.text = element_text(size = 8, colour = "black", angle = 0),                #Legend text
                 strip.text.x = element_text(size = 9, colour = "black", angle = 0),               #Facet x text size
                 strip.text.y = element_text(size = 9, colour = "black", angle = 270))             #Facet y text size

 guides_new <- guides(color = guide_legend(reverse=F), fill = guide_legend(reverse=F))    #Controls the order of your legend

 Colours <- 
 rainbow_hcl(length(levels(factor(StackedTable$DOM))), start = 30, end = 300)              #Yes I am Canadian so Colours has a "u"
    Colours[5] <- "#47984c"    #Green
    Colours[4] <- "#7b64b4"    #Purple-grey
    Colours[3] <- "#ff7f50"    #Orange
    Colours[2] <- "#cc3636"    #Red
    Colours[1] <- "#4783ba"    #Blue
```

## Creating two figures that will later be merged

```
#Making plot for panel A ("Dark condition")
 PlotA <-  
   ggplot(AncovasD, aes(x=as.numeric(Time.h), y=as.numeric(Measurement), fill=as.factor(Treatment))) +  
   geom_smooth(data=subset(AncovasD,Treatment =="MQ"),  aes(Time.h,Measurement,color=factor(Treatment)),method="lm", formula = y~x, se=T, show.legend = F) +
   geom_smooth(data=subset(AncovasD,Treatment =="DOM"), aes(Time.h,Measurement,color=factor(Treatment)),method="lm", formula = y~x, se=T, show.legend = F) +  #You need this line twice, once for each condition
   geom_errorbar(data=AncovasD, aes(ymin=Measurement-SD, ymax=Measurement+SD), width=0.2, colour="#73777a", size = 0.5) +  #Change width based on the size of your X-axis
   geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3, colour = "black", stroke = 1) +                           #colour is the outline of the circle, stroke is the thickness of that outline

   facet_grid(Treatment ~ UV) +                                                               #This places all your treatments into a grid. Change the order if you want them horizontal. Use "." if you do not want a label.
   geom_label(data=regressions_dataD.MQ, inherit.aes=FALSE, size=0.7,  colour=Colours[1],     #Add label for DOM regressions, specify same colour as your legend, change size depending on how large you want the text
           aes(x=-0.1, y=41, label=paste(" ",  "m == ",  slope,     "\n  " ,               #replace this line with the values you want: e.g. R-squared=("R2 == ", R2.Adj) ;  intercept=("b == ",  intercept). The "\n " makes a second line
                                         " ",  "p == ",  p.val                )))  +       #This completes the first label. Repeat same process for second label.
   geom_label(data=regressions_dataD.DOM, inherit.aes=FALSE, size=0.7,  colour=Colours[2], 
           aes(x=-0.1, y=4, label=paste(" ",  "m == ",  slope,     "\n  " ,
                                        " ",  "p == ",  p.val                )))

 #Now for the irradiated samples "light" plot (Panel B)
  PlotB <- 
   ggplot(AncovasL, aes(x=as.numeric(Time.h), y=as.numeric(Measurement), fill=as.factor(Treatment))) +   #Same as above but use your second dataframe.
   geom_smooth(data=subset(AncovasL,Treatment =="MQ"),  aes(Time.h,Measurement,color=factor(Treatment)),method="lm", formula = y~x, se=T, show.legend = F) +
   geom_smooth(data=subset(AncovasL,Treatment =="DOM"), aes(Time.h,Measurement,color=factor(Treatment)),method="lm", formula = y~x, se=T, show.legend = F) +
   geom_errorbar(data=AncovasL, aes(ymin=Measurement-SD, ymax=Measurement+SD), width=0.2, colour="#73777a", size = 0.5) +
   geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3, colour = "black",  stroke = 1) +

   facet_grid(Treatment ~ UV) +
   geom_label(data=regressions_dataL.MQ, inherit.aes=FALSE, size=0.7,  colour=Colours[1], 
           aes(x=-0.1, y=41, label=paste(" ",  "m == ",  slope,     "\n  " ,
                                         " ",  "p == ",  p.val                )))   +
   geom_label(data=regressions_dataL.DOM, inherit.aes=FALSE, size=0.7,  colour=Colours[2],  
           aes(x=-0.1, y=4, label=paste(" ",  "m == ",  slope,     "\n  " ,
                                        " ",  "p == ",  p.val                )))
```

## Almost there...

## Now add the theme to your figures && remove some parts for merging

```
#Now add themes to both plots and the things that differ (i.e. removing tick marks...)
  #Note: the following code can be integrated in the script above, but I find it cleaner to separate this part as these tend to change depending on the size of your pdf export. 
  #These were designed for a single column publication figure --> 3.75" wide by 6" high.
 PlotA <- PlotA +
   scale_fill_manual(values=Colours) + scale_colour_manual(values=Colours) +  
   scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-0.75,4.75), breaks=seq(0,4, by = 2)) +                      
   scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-10,165), breaks=seq(0,165, by = 50)) +              #Setting breaks only works if it matches your limits. First specify your limits, then set the breaks.
   theme_new + guides_new +
   theme(strip.text.y = element_blank(), legend.position = "none",                  #removes the Y facet strip && the legend   so I can stick the figures together
      plot.margin=unit(c(-0.9,0.8,0,0.5), "cm") ) +                              #again, these numbers are specific to a 3.75" wide figure. You will need to play with these numbers to adjust your figure.
   labs(title="", y="Biouptake (%)", x=" ",  color="",fill="")                      #remove X-axis label, we will only use one label in the next script.

 PlotB <- PlotB +
   scale_fill_manual(values=Colours) + scale_colour_manual(values=Colours) +        #calls the colours I specified earlier
   scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-0.75,4.75), breaks=seq(0,4, by = 2)) +              
   scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-10,165), breaks=seq(0,165, by = 50)) +              #Setting breaks only works if it matches your limits. First specify your limits, then set the breaks.
   theme_new +  guides_new +                                                        #calls the previously set theme and guides. 
   theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),                                             #adds a modifier to certain parts of the theme that are not the same for this plot
      axis.ticks.y.left = element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_text(hjust=2.2), #removes tick marks and a title.
      plot.margin=unit(c(-0.9,0.5,0,-1.3), "cm") ) +                             #Reduce panel margins by: First=top, Second=right, Third=bellow, Fourth=left --> To remember order, think TRouBLe
   labs(title="", y=" ", x="Irradiation time (h)",  color=" ",fill=" ")             #If you want a legend title, add it after color and after fill.
```

## Place both plots into one grid

```
 ggarrange(PlotA, PlotB, ncol = 2, nrow = 1,
        widths = c(1.65,1), heights = c(1,1),              #c(1.6 makes panelA same width as B when exporting figure at 3.75"). This ratio is only apparent after exporting the figure in next line.
        legend = "top", common.legend = TRUE)
```

## Exporting the figure.

```
 #Note: leave this line with a hashmark until you are happy with the figure. Otherwise you will accidently override some figures. 
   #ggsave("Name of figure HERE.svg",  width=3.75, height=6, path="~/Dropbox/")    #Note: change the .svg to .pdf if you do not need to modify anything



 #Hope this is helpful for some of you. Took me a long time to figure all of these parts out. 
 #This script takes some work to initially get going, but once done, it automates all of your figures with stats. 
 #Finally, you will likely need to do some slight modifications to the figure using a vector software. I'm on a Mac and recommend "Graphic". It can be found in the app store. If so, make sure to export as an SVG, and as a PDF once its modified by your software.
```

Your figure should look something like this. I made the text very small on purpose so that the boxes do not overlap with the regressions. If you just want quick and dirty figures, stop here. This should be sufficient for most.

But if the figure is bound for publication, use a vector editing software (I use Graphic on my Mac) and just place a white box on top of the labels and write it in manually (like I did in the first figure).

Cheers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, but this is not reproducible. Please share a reproducible example of your data.